# Getting wrong return value from PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, web-applications

I'm trying to make a php function that check that something is present in database or not, and return "1" or "null" based on this check. It successfully return "1" on first check if match is found but after that it always returns "1" until page is not refreshed.

So, I think that this is related to the cache or something like that. I used jQuery/AJAX to submit form from my HTML page.

Let me elaborate more clearly with my code with example.

functions.php (check username function):

```
 if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this file directly');

 // some functions
 function checkUser($email){
   $userFound = null;
   // check condition with if and for-each
   foreach.......
       if(......
         // user found
         $userFound = 1;
         break;
       }
     }
     return $userFound;
   }
```

Now I included this file in my "main.php" with

```
 define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
 include('functions.php');  // also tried : require 'functions.php';

 $email = $_POST['email'];
```

and initialized it with:

```
 if(!checkUser($email)){
   // perform action when user is not found
 }else{
   // echo an error msg
 }
```

This is the whole code that is responsible for the situation, now can anybody tell me that how to reset the return value of function on every submission? OR any solution.

Update (HTML code):

```
 $('html').on('click','.submit',function(e){
   window.clearTimeout(formreply);
   var $frm = $(this).parents('form');
   var serial = $frm.serialize();
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
   $.ajax({
     url: $frm.attr('action')+'?'+name+'=true',
     type: $frm.attr('method'),
     data: serial,
     success: function(response){
       if($frm.find('#formreply').length <= 0){
         $frm.prepend('<span id="formreply"></span><hr/>');
       }
       if(response.err){
         $frm.find('#formreply').empty().attr('class','formerr').html(response.err);
         return false;
       }else if(response.info){
         $frm.find('#formreply').empty().attr('class','forminfo').html(response.info);
       }else if(response.msg){
         $frm.find('#formreply').empty().attr('class','formmsg').html(response.msg);
       }
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       if($frm.find('#formreply').length <= 0){
         $frm.prepend('<span id="formreply"></span><hr/>');
       }
       $frm.find('#formreply').empty().attr('class','formerr').text(textStatus);
     }
   });
   formreply = window.setTimeout(function(){
     $('#formreply,hr').empty().remove();
   },4500);
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Update (providing more code for a better evaluation (main.php)):

```
 define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
 include('functions.php');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

 $admin = array(
   'err'=>null,
   'info'=>null,
   'msg'=>null
 );

 // more vars & REQUESTS

 if($_REQUEST['Register']){
   if(strlen($name)<4 || strlen($name)>32){
     $admin['err'] .= "Your name must be between 3 and 32 characters!";
   }
   if(!checkName($name)){
     $admin['err'] .= "Your name contains invalid characters!";
   }
   if($email){
     if(!checkEmail($email)){
       $admin['err'] .= "Your email is not valid!";
     }
   }else{
     $admin['err'] .= "Please enter your Email ID.";
   }
   if(strlen($password)<6 || strlen($password)>32){
     $admin['err'] .= "You must enter your password!! (6-32)";
   }
   if(!count($admin['err'])){
     if(checkUser($email) !== 1){ // also tried "!checkUser($email)"
       $admin['msg'] = "Thanks".checkUser($email);
     }else{
       $admin['info'] = "echoing info ".getName($email).checkUser($email);
     }
   }
 }

 echo json_encode($admin);
```

Comment: "_but after that if always returns "1" until page is not refreshed_" you need to keep checking this value without page refresh? If you are using AJAX to check, why do you `include('functions.php')`?

Comment: yeh exactly... bcz form is submitted from HTML to PHP via ajax, so page refresh is not necessary.

I use "include('functions.php')" bcz all functions and classes if defined in functions.php and "main.php" return result in JSON format.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not on server side, but on client (javascript) side. Can you provide some html/javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need a `break` in your `if`

```
function checkUser($email) {
    $userFound = null;
    // check condition with if and for-each
    foreach.......
        if(...) {
             // user found
             $userFound = 1;
             break;
        }
    }
    return $userFound;
}
```

Comment: I used "break;" in my function. But forgot to write it into my question.

Answer (score 0):

What are you foreach-ing over? If you never reset $userFound back to null it will always be 1 after it is changed the first time. You could either break out of the foreach when you change it to 1, return the function when you change it to 1 (you can just return 1 instead of setting the temp variable), or set it back to null after the if condition (though I think this might be pointless if you're not doing anything with it).

Comment: I used "break;" after user is found.

Comment: It might still be helpful to know what you're foreach-ing over. Also, you could return 1 after the if and return null at the end. You don't need the $userCheck variable. You could also try changing the check to if(checkUser($email) !== null) instead of checking the ! of the return value. Because PHP is loosely typed, it might be doing something weird, best to check type (===/!== is type-safe comparison) as often as possible. Are you sure the function is returning 1 every time? Or does it just appear that way? Try putting some probes in your code to see how the variables change.

Comment: ya I'm sure about it that the returning value is always "1" after the first usercheck is performed (used echo $checkUser($email))

Comment: Is your $email variable changing every time?

Comment: Yes, bcz this is a user inputted value

Comment: Yes, but are you sure it is actually changing in your code? Try echoing it.

Comment: Yeh I'm sure. bcz I tried both values ($email & checkUser) with echo.

Comment: Try echoing $userCheck at different points in the function (right after you set it to null and right after you set it to 1) to make sure it's changing inside of the function. Also, post some html/javascript code too. The problem might be on that side.

Comment: question updated for HTML code.
ok, i'll try to do echoing at different levels

Comment: I tried to trace the value. When the document is firstly initialized, than the value is null and returning null. After that, the value remains "1" until the page is not refreshed.

Comment: Try returning 1 or null and get rid of that variable all together. Like this: 
foreach.......
        if(...) {
             // user found
             return 1;
        }
    }
    return null;

Comment: I tried " if(checkUser($email) !== 1 ){ //user found }else{ //user not found}" with "return 1;" in if condition and "return null;" after foreach. Now, it echo "null" on first check only, after that starts returning "1". (until page is not refreshed)

Comment: And if I used these both returning value with " if(!checkUser($email)){..." than I successfully return "null" for just 1-2 seconds, after that replaced with "1".

Comment: question updated with more code (`HTML` & `main.php` code). please take a look. Thanks